# Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, исключения, dll, библиотеки

Есть dll, доступа к исходному коду у меня нет, идет в составе sdk к прибору.

На одном компьютере программа, использующая эту dll, нормально отрабатывает, на другом - вылетает с unhandled exception в этой dll: Access violation reading location.

Отличий в установленных c++ runtime libraries нет, брандмауэр отключен и там и там, Dependency Walker показывает, что необходимые библиотеки присутствуют

В какую сторону думать, чтобы на втором компьютере перестало вылетать?

P.S. для тех, кто в комментариях не поверил, что есть только dll - единственная работа с этой библиотекой представляет собой:

1. подкинуть ее в папку с программой
2. в файле конфигурации формата .ini прописать название этой либы

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: ¿Как программа использует dll, если исходников нет? Как минимум, заголовочные файлы значит есть. Соответственно проверяйте, правильно ли она используется и нет ли ошибок в самом приложении.

Comment: @user7860670, эта dll идет в составе SDK к прибору. Только она и есть

Comment: *"Только она и есть"* противоречит *"идет в составе SDK к прибору"*, ¿не так ли?

Comment: @user7860670, да что Вы докопались, еще и заминусовали, я говорю как есть - НЕТ НИЧЕГО КРОМЕ DLL

Comment: Тогда объясняйте во всех подробностях, как вы ее используете, когда даже заголовочных файлов нет. А вообще мутные вопросы, для которых нельзя предоставить [mcve], являются оффтопиком на этом сайте.

Comment: @user7860670, вопрос дополнен

Comment: exe - ваш, или тоже из состава sdk?

Comment: ¿Ну а как программа загружает эту библиотеку и как с ней работает? ¿На каком этапе задействуется С++, указанный а тегах?

Comment: @Chorkov, думаю, исходники exe можно найти. Но текст ошибки именно на dll указывает, вот в чем дело

Comment: @user7860670, с++ в тегах из-за того, что Dependency Walker раскрыл либу, она зависит (в стеке это тоже было видно) от с++ библиотек

Answer (score 0):

0. Ошибки работы с памятью, могут приводить к падению в разных местах, в т.ч. в сторонних dll. Используйте _CrtCheckMemory, AddressSanitizer  ...  Попробуйте написать минимальное приложение вызывающее эту DLL, и имеющее разное поведение на машинах.
1. проверить документацию на эту dll. Проверить все требования к вызову функций этой dll. Записать в логи все данные поступающие на вход этой DLL на обоих машинах, потом сравнить. Возможно, ошибка не на стороне dll.
2. проверить к чему программа обращается (файлы, реестр). Возможно, неверно написана обработка случая отсутствия какого-то файла с данными.
3. возможно, неверно написана обработка случая отсутствия какой-то динамически подключаемой библиотеки (в т.ч. COM). Запустить процесс под отладчиком, на машине где работает, составить список реально загружаемых библиотек.
4. возможно, DLL содержит неопределенное поведение. Туи без исходников - никак.

Comment: "Записать в логи все данные поступающие на вход этой DLL" - какими средствами это можно сделать? Или Вы имеете в виду, прописать такую логику в минимальном приложении?

Comment: @qwerty Внести соответствующие исправления в вызывающее приложение. У вас же есть от него исходники...